# How to change user for "pio eventserver"?

Tags: predictionio

I have:

```
$ pio eventserver

[INFO] [Console$] Creating Event Server at 127.0.0.1:7070
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'pio'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:959)
```

That's because I don't have the user `pio` in my MYSQL database. How do I change the username for the pio command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the file `conf/pio-env.sh` in your PIO installation and edit the following lines:

```
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_MYSQL_TYPE=jdbc
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_MYSQL_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost/pio
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_MYSQL_USERNAME=pio
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_MYSQL_PASSWORD=pio
```